# Restarting windows form application with different form initialized first

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing a reminder project using `Windows Forms`. I am using two forms, namely `reminderform` and `reminder`. I am using `reminderform` for setting the reminders and to store details like timings in a database. I have written code for `reminder` to trigger the reminder using timings stored in database. Problem is that every time I have to restart the application manually with `reminder` form initialized first in order to trigger the reminder set using `reminderform` form. Is there a way I can do it in the program itself.

To set the reminder I have to use:

```
static class Program
{  
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new reminderform());
    }
}
```

To make the application trigger the reminder I have to use:

```
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new reminder());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `static void Main()` to `static void Main(string[] args)`, and send a command line argument when activating the program from the database. you can access it from the `args` array in Main.

Answer (score 1):

`reminderform` should not be interacting with your database (to store details like timings as you say). That logic should be encapsulated in a different class. The idea is to separate your model from your view. Not doing so makes it difficult to select the correct view based on information in your model (i.e. your database), as you have found out. Once you have separated out this logic, then you can select the appropriate view to display to your users. For example (and bear in mind this is very hypothetical):

```
ReminderDatabase db = new ReminderDatabase();
var remindersCollection = db.Fetch();

foreach (var reminder in remindersCollection)
{
    if (reminder.InspectTimings().ReminderShouldActivate)
    {
        // show the reminder to the user
    }
}
```

You should probably not be changing the form passed to `Application.Run`. I would personally have my main form run with an icon in the system tray, and show reminders with `Outlook`-style popups.